# Get siblings from parent id and exclude itself Laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, siblings

**CONTEXT**

I am managing products. This is a shoe store. I would like to offer a view of the other variants.

The database is shaped like this:

[image]

For example you can have a leather shoe (id 1), and there is 3 variants of this shoe: a black (id 1), a brown (id 2), and a grey (id 3).

What I try to do is to construct a Laravel relationship to be able, from one variant, to get its siblings. Here is what it looks like in the database according to the example I mentioned.

```
SHOE
id
====
1

SHOE_VARIANT
id  shoeId  colorId
===================
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   1       3
...
8   2       5
9   3       2
10  3       4
```

In this case, if the user is viewing the black variant (id 1), I whish I could show him the 2 others variants (brown, id 2, and grey, id 3).

**QUESTION**

How can I construct a Laravel relationship in order to retrieve siblings from a parent id, and make sure the current record itself is not included?

**EXPERIMENTS**

I already tried to construct a relationship like below, but the current record itself is included and I can't figure out how to exclude the record itself because I did not find how to get the current id of the record.

```php
// app/ShoeVariant.php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ShoeVariant extends Model {
  public function siblings() {
    return $this->hasMany("App\ShoeVariant", "shoeId", "shoeId");
  }
}
```

This means:

> For the current shoe variant, get the shoe variants that matches knowing that you should match the foreign column named "shoeId" and the local column named "shoeId"

So if 2 shoe variants share the same column "shoeId", this works. Stuck in excluding the current record from these results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
public function siblings() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ShoeVariant', 'shoeId', 'shoeId')
                ->where('id', '!=', $this->id);
}
```

Just filter out the current variant by id and get all the others.

Alternatively, you can just make a new property:

```
public function getVariantsAttribute() {
    return $this->siblings->reject(function($elem) {
       return $elem->id == $this->id;
    });
}
```

And then use it in code like:

```
$variants = $model->variants; // all except this one
```

Comment: Seems like it did not work on my machine (thank you for the double "shoeId" parameter, I found it in the same time!).

Comment: I just tested it, works fine for me. Make sure that "id" parameter name is correct. If it doesn't work I can proposer an alternative solution, but this is the quickest.

Comment: I used `dd` to print `$this->id` on the `sibling` method, and in Insomnia I got `null`. Maybe drop me your second alternative and I'll see if it work?

Comment: Added 2nd option. It's kinda weird that id = null for you. Does the model have the id attribute?

Comment: Yep, I also added `protected $primaryKey = "id";` to be sure...

Comment: You have to rely on id anyway, so you need to make sure `$this->id` is not null because you have nothing else to compare :)

Comment: I'll just mark your answer as solving my problem and work around this issue thanks mate ;)

Comment: Okay so looks like if I do in php artisan tinker `ShoeVariant::find(1)->siblings` it got the filter to work because `$this->id` is equal to `1`.

However, if I use it like that : `ShoeVariant::with("siblings")->get()`, the value of `$this->id` is null. I am using Laravel 5.8, is that a bug?

Comment: No I think that's the expected behaviour. You can just use the second method to access the variants inside a foreach loop when you iterate over the models.